# Getting test results

Tags: java

First let me just say I have limited programming experience so please forgive my lack of knowledge in advance. I created a free website that helps people prepare for a test (it ask 1 question at a time, tells the user if they are right or wrong, and gives the correct answer then moves onto the next question/webpage). What I don't understand (and most often asked for by users) is how can I give a user the score (%) when the test is completed? If anyone could provide any help I'd be grateful

Comment: `score(%) = correct_answers/total_questions`

Comment: Keep track of the number of correct answers and then use basic math.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many questions were answered correctly, and then after they've answered all questions, divide the number of correct answers by how many questions there were total.

For example:

```
if(answer==correctAnswer) //(or however you determine the answer is correct)
{
    numberOfCorrectAnswers++;
    //...and whatever else you need to do here
}

//...
//...and after answering the final question:
percentCorrect = ((double)numberOfCorrectAnsers)/numberOfQuestions;
```

In this case, you have to cast `numberOfCorrectAnsers` to a double so that the division gives you a double back—otherwise, Java will round your answer down to the nearest integer (i.e., 5/6 = 0)